# Check string length with variable in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want a function written in Clojure that checks if my given String is bigger than my given number and if so, my function says true otherwise it says false.
Now i've come up with the following code, but it gives the following error: 
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn user/checker (form-init1692807253513002836.clj:1)

The code i've come up with is:

```
(defn checker [str, num] 
  (cond 
    (> (count str) num) "True"
    :else "False"
  )
) 
(checker "test" 6)
```

Can someone explain why count str is considered as a Long and/or how this function can be fixed?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, the example you pasted appears to work fine. One common cause of this is editing the file and needing to load it. in emacs it's C-k (by default) in InteliJ it's "load namespace"

Comment: Well you're right, after I restarted Clojure my code worked....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to “fix” your function by considering some Clojure
idioms that apply to your snippet:

- booleans are built in; no need to use `"True"`/`"False"` strings
  (unless you’re just using these as a placeholder example for
  something else)
- don’t need to be explicit about the return booleans since `>`
  already returns a boolean
- you’re measuring “length” rather than “bigness”, so use a
  descriptive function name; `strlen` is probably common
- since boolean return value you can end with `?`
- probably avoid `str` as var name
- switch the comparison order to use `<` instead of `>`, based on [Elements of Clojure](https://leanpub.com/elementsofclojure) recommendation

With those in mind, your function simplifies down to:

```
(defn strlen-exceeds? [s n]
  (< n (count s)))
```

(And now it’s short enough that you might not even need it to be an
explicit function.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should work, but for this case, don't use `cond` use `if`.

```
(defn checker [str, num] 
  (if (> (count str) num) 
     "True"
    "False")) 


> (checker "a" 1)
"False"
> (checker "a" 2)
"False"
> (checker "ab" 2)
"False"
> (checker "ab" 2)
```